# How to avoid repetition in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been writing some custom jQuery validation for a form and have found I am writing the same elements several times. I could really use some help to be more 'DRY' if possible. I've included an example below if anyone could point me in the right direction i'd very much appreciate it.

```
<div class="first-name-wrapper">
    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input class="first-name" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
    <div class="validation-msg first-name-error hide">
        <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation`enter code here`-circle"></i> Please tell us your first name</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="last-name-wrapper">
    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input class="last-name" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
    <div class="validation-msg last-name-error hide">
        <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Please tell us your last name</p>
</div>

$('.first-name').on('input', function () {
    if($('.first-name').val() != "") {
        $('.first-name-wrapper').removeClass('has-error');
        $('.first-name-error').addClass('hide');
    }
});
//last name
$('.last-name').on('input', function () {
    if($('.last-name').val() != "") {
        $('.last-name-wrapper').removeClass('has-error');
        $('.last-name-error').addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Essentially all this does is check that when the input has something typed in it, it finds the containing wrapper and removes the 'has-error' class and hides the validation message if the input is not empty.

Comment: There might be some ways to improve this, especially when using the current context with ```this``` - please show some of your HTML markup as well so we can give you a helpful answer

Comment: you could use a class ```.nameInput``` or ```.input``` if you have many and the logic is the same. and you should also use ```this``` to avoid multiple query ```if($('.last-name')``` ```$('.last-name-wrapper')``` ```$('.last-name-error')```

Comment: Thank you, I have edited the question to include a snippet of html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this code more DRY (ie. Don't Repeat Yourself), you can put common classes on the elements to group them by behaviour. Then you can hook event handlers to those classes and use DOM traversal to relate the elements to each other.

Also note that you need an `else` statement in order to display the validation messages and error class on the wrapper. This can be achieved more simply by using `toggleClass()` and providing a boolean value to indicate under what circumstances the class should be added/removed. Try this:

```js
$('.field').on('input', function() {
  var $field = $(this);
  $field.closest('.field-wrapper').toggleClass('has-error', $field.val().trim() == "");
  $field.next('.validation-msg').toggleClass('hide', $field.val().trim() != "");
});
```

```css
.has-error { color: #C00; }
.hide { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field-wrapper">
  <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
  <input class="field" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
  <div class="validation-msg hide">
    <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation`enter code here`-circle"></i> Please tell us your first name</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="field-wrapper">
  <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
  <input class="field" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
  <div class="validation-msg hide">
    <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Please tell us your last name</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The benefit of this pattern is that it is infinitely extensible, as long as the HTML structure around the fields remains consistent.

Answer (score 2):

You should delegate your logic to a function. Something along the lines of:

```
let validateInput = (el) => {
    if(el.target.value != ""){
        $(el.target.className + "-wrapper").removeClass("has-error");
        $(el.target.className + "-error").addClass("hide");

        //Alternatively ES6 syntax which is less error prone:
        $(`${el.target.className}-wrapper`).removeClass("has-error");
        $(`${el.target.className }-error`).addClass("hide");
    }
}

$(".first-name").on("input", (e) => validateInput(e));
$(".last-name").on("input", (e) => validateInput(e));
```

There are many different ways depending on frameworks and the markup you have. You could also look into iterating over your elements and dynamically hook up all the events in one go.

Comment: Alternatively just `$(".first-name").on("input", validateInput);`. That way it's more succinct, and will now work in IE.

Answer (score 0):

```
// This way you can target div or class anything;
// keep adding your object of element in **validationElements** array;
let validationElements = [{
        target: '.first-name',
        wrapperTarget: '.first-name-wrapper',
        errorTarget: '.first-name-error'
    },
    {
        target: '.last-name',
        wrapperTarget: '.last-name-wrapper',
        errorTarget: '.last-name-error'
    }
];


validationElements.forEach(function(element) {
    $(element.target).on('input', function() {
        if ($(element.target).val() != "") {
            $(element.wrapperTarget).removeClass('has-error');
            $(element.errorTarget).addClass('hide');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery multiple selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and make use of the $(this) selector to process the active element.

```
<div>
    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input class="first-name" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
    <div class="validation-msg">
        <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation`enter code here`-circle"></i> Please tell us your first name</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input class="last-name" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
    <div class="validation-msg">
        <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Please tell us your last name</p>
</div>


$('.first-name, .last-name').on('input', function(){
    var element = $(this); 
    if(element.val() != "") {
        element.parent().removeClass('has-error');
        element.next().addClass('hide');
    }
});
```

Also note that **you can use css to hide the error message**, based on the 'has-error' class of the parent. In that case, you will no longer need to toggle the 'hide' class on the validation message, meaning less js code (https://codepen.io/AndrewRed/pen/yLBrLxv?editors=1111)

```
.validation-msg {
  display: none;
}

.has-error .validation-msg {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that the other solutions are more flexible and extensible but this chaining is useful in another area that I was looking at :)