# Check all inputs in form with a given class are not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a multi-step form so some of the buttons are not submit buttons, t
hey simply take you to the next step.

On click of one of these 'fake' buttons I want to check that a given set of inputs is not empty.

I have done this so far (just a couple of inputs included as an example) but I don't want to have to do this for every input:

```
<div class="field-wrapper first-name-wrapper">
    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input class="text-validation first-name" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
    <div class="validation-msg first-name-error hide">
        <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Please tell us your first name</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field-wrapper last-name-wrapper">
    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input class="text-validation last-name" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
    <div class="validation-msg last-name-error hide">
        <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Please tell us your last name</p>
</div>

if ($('.first-name').val() == "") {
    $('.first-name-wrapper').addClass('has-error');
}
if ($('.last-name').val() == "") {
    $('.last-name-wrapper').addClass('has-error');
}
```

How can I check each of the inputs is not null without repeating myself and then assign the has-error class to the individual item?

Comment: Is this all inside a `<form>`?

Comment: If you use the HTML I showed you in your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58112857/how-to-avoid-repetition-in-jquery) all you need to do is loop over `$('.field').each()` and then check the `val()` within that loop. Alternatively, just add the `required` attribute to the HTML and use the [`:invalid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) selector in CSS to add the styling.

Comment: Yes it is in a form. I can't use the required attribute as its a multi-step form so the submit isn't until several steps later. I can use the each function though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the class `.text-validation` to access all input and apply change event ,

so if `value = ""` just add has error to parent wrapper div as below snippet :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".text-validation").on("change",function(e){
    $(this).val().length == 0 ?  $(this).parent().addClass("has-error") : $(this).parent().removeClass("has-error");
    console.log( $(this).parent());
  });
  
  $("#btn").on("click",function(a) {
    $(".text-validation").change();
  })
  
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display:none;
  color:red;
}

.field-wrapper.has-error .hide {
  display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field-wrapper first-name-wrapper">
    <label for="first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input class="text-validation first-name" type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
    <div class="validation-msg first-name-error hide">
        <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Please tell us your first name</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="field-wrapper last-name-wrapper">
    <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input class="text-validation last-name" type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name">
    <div class="validation-msg last-name-error hide">
        <p><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Please tell us your last name</p>
</div>
<br >
<button id="btn">submit</button>
```